# Time-like null-like and space-like killing vector fields

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, definition, vector-fields, causality

If the Lie derivative of a metric tensor with respect to some vector field is zero then the vector is called killing vector (KV). 
The KV can be time-like, null-like and space-like.

What is the physical meaning of time-like, null-like and space-like killing vectors?

Comment: So you already know the mathematical definition, and are asking for the physical meaning?

Comment: Do you understand that they're interpreted as global, infinitesimal symmetries, but you just want to understand the distinction among the three types?

Comment: For time-like killing vector there is a time-translational symmetry. But how can we know that a killing vector is time-like. I know the mathematical definition of time-like killing vector : (Ka.Kb > 0 for the metric signature (+,-,-,-) ) but what is the physical meaning of this mathematical expression ?